# Inline edit - record not updating [only last record updating]

Tags: apex, soql, salesforce-id, sosl

whenever i used to edit these records by inline edit function - only the last records getting updated, rest of the records not updating.
[image]

visualforce code:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Account" extensions="saveAndRedirect"  tabStyle="Account_custom__tab">

    <apex:form > 
    <apex:pageblock title="Record Details" >
    <apex:pageblockSection title="Recent Record Details" collapsible="false">
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="update, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
    changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.accountnumber}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.rating}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.industry}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!a.Active__c}"/>
    </apex:pageblocktable>
     <apex:commandButton id="update" action="{!quickUpdat}" value="UpdateRecord" />
    </apex:pageblockSection>   
    </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>       </apex:page>
```

apex code:

```
public with sharing class saveAndRedirect{
  private Apexpages.standardcontroller controller;
  public saveAndRedirect(Apexpages.standardcontroller controller){
  this.controller = controller;
  }
   List<Account> acc{get;set;}
   public String message{get;set;} 
   public List<Account> getacc()
   {
     acc = [select  id,name,accountnumber,rating,industry,Active__c from account 
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5];
     return acc;
   } 
    public PageReference quickUpdat(){
    try{
    update acc;
    return ApexPages.CurrentPage();
    }catch(Exception e){
    message='Data Base error during saving...';
    ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, message));
    return null;
    }
    }       
    }
```

Comment: Replace your line `List<Account> acc{get;set;}` with: `private List<Account> acc;`. You already defined your getter with the method `getAcc();`

Comment: i replaced,eventhough its not updating the records, only last record getting updated(if i update)

Answer (score 0):

Try This..

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" standardController="Account" extensions="saveAndRedirect"  tabStyle="Account_custom__tab">

    <apex:form > 
    <apex:pageblock title="Record Details" >
    <apex:pageblockSection title="Recent Record Details" collapsible="false">
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!acc}" var="a">
    <apex:inlineEditSupport showOnEdit="update, cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" event="ondblclick" 
    changedStyleClass="myBoldClass" resetFunction="resetInlineEdit"/>
    <apex:column headerValue="Name" >
     <apex:outputField value="{!a.name}"/>
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="AccountNumber">
      <apex:outputField value="{!a.accountnumber}" />
    </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Rating">
     <apex:outputField value="{!a.rating}"/>
     </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Industry">
     <apex:outputField value="{!a.industry}"/>
     </apex:column>
    <apex:column headerValue="Active">
     <apex:outputField value="{!a.Active__c}"/>
     </apex:column>
    </apex:pageblocktable>
     <apex:commandButton id="update" action="{!quickUpdat}" value="UpdateRecord" />
    </apex:pageblockSection>   
    </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
```

Comment: Some explanation along with code in answer would be better.